# SQL procedure return empty table despite of working query

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I've a problem with procedure in SQL.

My code in SQL which is working is like that:

```
 SELECT * FROM ble.lampa_elektronowa
 WHERE id_typ =
 (SELECT id_typ FROM typ
 WHERE typ = 'pierwszy')
```

And the result of this query is

[image: here]

When i'm trying to write the procedure using this code (IF Akcja = 'DODAJ_DATA' THEN):

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procedura_lampa`( 
 IN Akcja          VARCHAR(25),
 IN id_lampa       INT,
 IN nazwa_lampy    VARCHAR(50),
 IN id_pomiar      INT,
 IN punkt          INT,
 IN krzywa         INT,
 IN Ia             FLOAT,
 IN IsVariable     FLOAT,
 IN Vg             FLOAT,
 IN Va             FLOAT,
 IN Vs             FLOAT,
 IN Vf             FLOAT,   
 IN id_typ         INT,
 IN TYP            VARCHAR(45),
 IN zapas15        INT, 
 IN zapas16        INT,  
 IN zapas17        INT,
 IN zapas18        INT,
 IN zapas19        INT,
 OUT Komunikat     VARCHAR(200)
 )
BEGIN
IF Akcja = 'LISTA' THEN
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM ble.lampa_elektronowa;
        SET @Komunikat = 'Wyświetlono';
        SET Komunikat = @Komunikat;

    END;
END IF;

IF Akcja = 'DODAJ_DATA' THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ble.data (data)
        VALUES (NOW());
    END;
END IF;

IF Akcja = 'WYPELNIJCBIDLAMPY' THEN
    BEGIN

        SELECT nazwa_lampy FROM ble.lampa_elektronowa
        WHERE id_typ =
        (SELECT id_typ FROM typ
        WHERE typ = TYP);
    END;
END IF;   

END
```

and I'm trying to call this procedure using this code:

```
 call procedura_lampa('WYPELNIJCBIDLAMPY', @id_lampy, @nazwa_lampy, @id_pomiar, @punkt, @krzywa, @Ia, @IsVariable, @Vg, @Va, @Vs, @Vf, @id_typ, 'pierwszy', @zapas15, @zapas16, @zapas17, @zapas18, @zapas19, @Komunikat) ;
```

, the result of the query is empty.
The "typ" table looks like

[image: that].

Why it doesn't work?
This should returns some results.

Comment: Edit your question and (1) Show how you are calling the stored procedures; (2) Explain what not working means.

Comment: Fix your question title please. Make it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have two semicolons in your procedure. One after sub query,  another  after END.  Remove the first one for sure. If you still have error let us know what is its content.

Comment: When I remove the first semicolon, the MySQL Workbench shows the error "Syntax error: extraneous input found - expected 'semicolon'".

Comment: Did you try to put some debug printing to check if you are entering the right if statement? It seems your conditions are exclusive,  can you try with if.. Else and see then?